# SASS grid system WITHOUT edge gutters

Tags: css, layout, sass, grid-system, gutter

I'm looking for a sass grid system that does *not* have edge gutters, a.k.a. there is no left gutter applied to the first column, and no right gutter applied to the last column.

Normally you could simply use :first-child / :last-child to remove the gutters, but then the first/last columns would be slightly wider than the rest (I'm using padding as gutters).

Is there a grid system that supports this? Or would I be better off writing it on my own?

**Edit**: I decided to go ahead and try writing my own solution :) Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution I came up with, hopefully this helps someone else with similar requirements:

```
@mixin grid($total, $gutter) {
    float: left;
    width: percentage(1 / $total);

    @for $i from 1 through $total {
        &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
            padding-left: ($i - 1) / $total * $gutter + 0px;
            padding-right: ($total - $i) / $total * $gutter + 0px;
        }
    }

    &:first-of-type { padding-left: 0; }
    &:last-of-type { padding-right: 0; }
}
```

Then to use it simply call:

```
@include grid(4, 30px); // Creates a 4 column grid with 30px inner gutters
```

Note that this is an extremely simple solution that will only handle situations where each column is the same width.